# Forming a sparse feature matrix data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to expand the 'features' column of this data frame so that I create a new data frame where these features become the column names.

For example. From this,

[image: Raw matrix]

To this,

[image: Features matrix]

My solution works but I don't think it is very good because there are lots of for-loops. Maybe there is a better approach thats takes advantage of features of the Pandas.DataFrame class?

The code to generate the feature matrix is below,

```
def feature_data_frame_by_exploding_column(input_df, col_name):

    # Create data frame with same columns minus the column you want to explode
    df = input_df.copy()
    del df[col_name]

    # The items that you want to become new features
    all_new_features = []
    new_feature_list = input_df[col_name].values
    for ingred_list in new_feature_list:
        all_new_features.extend(ingred_list) # Extend vs append!

    # Add new features as columns of zeros
    for feature in all_new_features:
        df[feature] = 0

    # For each row in data frame set values that need to be 1
    for index in df.index:
        ingreds_arr = new_feature_list[index]
        df.loc[index, ingreds_arr] = 1

    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "features"])
df['id'] = [0,1]
df['features'] = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
df

feature_data_frame_by_exploding_column(df,"features")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit learn's [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer) creates a binary matrix from labels. You can extract `feature` column from pandas dataframe and apply it:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
new_array = mlb.fit_transform(feature)
```

Additionally by specifying `MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)` you will get a truly sparse output (useful if the number of different features is large).

---

Sample output:

```
>>> MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]])
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```